# Can an awarded tag-badge be withdrawn?

Tags: support, badges

For instance, recently I have earned two gold badges: [commutative-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commutative-algebra) and [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) tags badges. I wonder if such a badge (or any other) can be withdrawn if, for instance, people downvote many of my answers.

Comment: Congrats on getting the tag badges.

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6848/can-badges-be-unearned

Comment: @MartinSleziak an answer in the linked to post is not up to date (in that the practice of not awarding new badges in case there are "excess" badges got discontinued long ago). I am not sure what is the best course of action.

Comment: @quid If my answer needs updating, feel free to edit it. (It is CW anyway.) If the other answer needs updating, I'd suggest leaving a comment there. (If possible, with some reference to meta.SE.) Since the answerer is still active on math.SE, I guess they might update the answer or at least add some warning, that the answer is outdated with link to some relevant more recent post(s).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tag badges are withdrawn when one no longer meets the criteria (general badges are basically never withdrawn, that is they are certainly not automatically taken on failing the criteria later, yet only  possibly in cases of  cheating and related).

See "What can cause a badge to be lost/revoked/taken away after it is awarded?" in the relevant FAQ on the general meta: [How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

Comment: Thanks. Then please don't downvote my answers :)

Comment: You  are welcome. I changed the link to  a more official one.